# The existence of inverse function of "rotated" $f(x)=x^{3} \sin{\frac{1}{x}}$ on the neighborhood of x=0?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I'm a bit confused about the existence of inverse function of a function. Let's consider the "rotated" version of $f(x)=x^{3} \sin{\frac{1}{x}}$, say, rotate it counterclockwise around the origin through a small enough angle $\theta$, to yield a wave that straddles a line $y=kx$, where $k=\tan{\theta}$.

Then we see since the rotation angle is very small, any straight line $y=c$ must intercept the figure of the function at least 2 points(when c is small enough), thus the inverse function on any neighborhood of x=0 cannot exist.

But by inverse function theorem, $f$ is continuously differentiable, $f^{\prime}=k>0$, and $f(0)=0$, it should have inverse function on a neighborhood of x=0.

Why?

Comment: You say *Then we see since the rotation angle is very small, any straight line $y=c$ must intercept the figure of the function at least 2 points(when c is small enough)*. Are you sure of that? Can you prove it properly? Also, as you rotate the curve, you get a curve in $\mathbb R^2$. But is it still a function?

Comment: there $f'(0)=0$, so $f$ is not invertible in any neighborhood of zero (Im assuming here that $f(0):=0$, so $f$ is continuously differentiable)

Comment: After we rotate it, $f'(0)$ is no longer $0$.